# Simple combinations and commissions

Tags: combinatorics

A staff committee by $3$ men and $3$ women to be chosen from a pool of $8$ men and $5$ women. What the number of committees in the event that H and M are not allowed to be on the committee simultaneously

**Attempt:** Let's call $H$ the man referred to in the statement, and $M$ the woman he doesn't like. We can divide into cases:

Case 1: $H$ participates, so $M$ will not participate

$\displaystyle \binom{7}{2} \cdot \binom{4}{3}$

Case 2: $M$ participates, so $H$ does not participate

$\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} \cdot \binom{7}{3}$

So, adding up the possible outcomes we get $126$. The answer is $434$, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The grammar of this question is off, so I am not clear on what exactly you want.  You ask for the number of committees in the event that $H$ and $M$ are not allowed to be on the committee simultaneously?  If so, you missed the case of neither $H$ nor $M$ participating.  Note, this can be done faster with less arithmetic if you were to have counted all committees and just removed the bad ones.

Comment: You should never change a question after an answer to the original question has been posted.

Comment: @trueblueanil I think the question should now make more sense

Comment: Yes, it does make more sense, but changing a question after an answer has been received can invalidate the posted answer.

Comment: @trueblueanil Oh, I understand. Thank you for the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't clearly phrased, apparently it all depends on the alpha female's *decision* to be or not to be on the committee, so

$\binom42\binom73 + \binom43\binom83 = 434$

### PS

The question has been changed, fortunately the answer doesn't !
All committees minus committees including both "enemies" $\binom83\binom53 - \binom72\binom42 = 434$